# Debo crear una lista fuera de los metodos para los registros que tengo, ya que cada vez que se ejecuta el metodo me crea una nueva lista

Tags: java, netbeans, arraylist

Asi es como tengo declaradas las listas pertenecientes a los objeto
pero la creacion de las listas (Lineas 35-37) quiero dejarlas despues de instanciarlas (Lineas 20-22), por que no me permite realizar esa accion?
Puede ser la visibilidad de las listas?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Modifica la pregunta y agrega el código ( como texto).

Comment: Hola, Bienvenido@. Las publicaciones que no contienen el codigo en una imagen, no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Por favor, revisa [como hacer un pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y edita tu pregunta para que podamos ayudarte. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

El titulo lo dice todo, siempre que llames a `registrarAnimales` estas creando devuelta la lista, por lo tanto los datos no se mantienen, para evitarlo simplemente inicia las listas en el constructor de la clase y no vuelvas a iniciarlas.

```
public Metodos() {
    vTerrestres = new ArrayList<>();
    vAcuaticos = new ArrayList<>();
    vAereos = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Ahora al hacer `new Metodos();` el constructor inicia las 3 listas, para que otros métodos de la clase puedan operar sobre estas.

Ejemplo:

```
Metodos metodos = new Metodos();
metodos.registrarAnimal(1);
metodos.registrarAnimal(2);
```

En la imagen no se ve bien, pero imagino que el `for` lo único que hace es ingresar la cantidad de animales dada por el `Scanner`, y agrega el tipo de animal a la lista dependido del numero que le das por parámetro al llamar al método.

Comment: Gracias lograste solucionarme la pregunta :)